# I'm trying to use a calculated column which uses ranking, to then convert to start rating with case statement. Any ideas?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Trying to get the 2nd piece of this to work based on the ranking of the first.

```
#ee balance rank
PERCENT_RANK()
OVER (PARTITION BY Industry_Group 
ORDER BY (NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT/PARTCP_ACCOUNT_BAL_CNT) ASC) AS EE_Balance_Acct_Rank,

#ee balance rank star ratings
Case when EE_Balance_Account_Rank between 0 and .1
Then .5
Else 5
End ee_balance_stars,
```

Tried using the ordered by calc but then I lose the ranking by industry_group

Answer (score 0):

I generally just two step this - first a query to select your percent rank, then from this result set another query to complete the desired results.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN T.EE_Balance_Account_Rank BETWEEN 0 AND .1
        THEN .5
        ELSE 5
    END ee_balance_stars,
    T.x,
    T.y,
    T.z
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        x, y, z, EE_Balance_Acct_Rank
        PERCENT_RANK()
        OVER (PARTITION BY Industry_Group 
    ORDER BY (NET_ASSETS_EOY_AMT/PARTCP_ACCOUNT_BAL_CNT) ASC) AS EE_Balance_Acct_Rank
    ) T
```

Comment: Thanks! still playing with to get it to work.